# How to achieve this delimiter in C?

Tags: c

Suppose I will enter the data in this way.

```
18-MAR-1995
```

Now I want to store this one data into different variables using one single scanf() function.

Let say the variables are,

```
int dd,yy;
char month[3];
```

1. 18 will store in dd variable
2. MAR will store in month variable
3. 1995 will store in yy variable

I tried this one

```
scanf("%d[^-]%s[^-]%d",&dd,s,&yy);
```

[IDEONE LINK HERE](http://ideone.com/K2k8MD)

Comment: A 3 character month will require a 4 character buffer

Comment: What is the issue you are having with this?

Comment: You tried `scanf("%d[^-]%s[^-]%d",&dd,s,&yy)` and what happened?

Comment: @StoryTeller You may still able to store 3 bytes of data in char month[3] variable,

Comment: @PritamKarmakar - Not with `scanf` and `%s`. RTFM, because you have UB in your program as it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that `scanf` syntax is different from regular expressions; it seems you're confusing the two. Non-special characters match themselves, so `-` needs no special treatment. Furthermore, `%s` always expects a whitespace-terminated string (word), so you need `%3c` to match three characters exactly.

So the correct format string is:

```
scanf("%d-%3c-%d", &dd, month, &yy);
```

Note that no terminating `'\0'` byte will be added to `month`! So this is well-defined behaviour, but don't try to use `month` as a null-terminated string.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning exactly how to null-terminate `month`.

Comment: @Dan: there is no way to null-terminate the 3-character array because too little storage was allocated.  If at least 4 bytes of storage was allocated, then it would be reasonable to use `%3[^-]` as the scan set.  That would null terminate the string.  You could also use just `%3s`.

Answer (score 3):

The issue with your code is that you used `[^-]` which means stop when you see `[^-]` literally. You want to only match `-`.
So that is wrong.
Try this one

```
scanf("%d-%[^-]-%d", &d, m, &y);
```

Here you stop the parsing of `%d` when `-` is found and the string stops when next `-` is found. Final integer goes into `y`.

Also as mentioned by StoryTeller you need 4 characters for storing "MAR" if you want to treat it as a string.

Here is a [demo](https://ideone.com/tRzP7f)

Comment: Actually `[` in OP's code means to match the `[` character in the input  (as opposed to `%[` which you seem to be describing)

Comment: @M.M Ah! yes, in the non - % regions `[` will be treated as `[`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

// for format dd-mmm-yyyy format ex. 18-MAR-1995

```
int dd,yy;
char month[4];   // note the extra char for null char at end.

char* sz = "18-MAR-1995";
if (sscanf(sz, "%d-%3s-%4d", &dd, month, &yy) != 3)
{
   // sz is not in expected format
}
```